# REST API request body with python dictionary

Tags: python, json, aws-glue, api-gateway

I am working with  AWS REST API. I am trying to invoke glue job via REST API. For that, I need to pass arguments as JSON object. And withing this json object, I should pass python dictionary as JSON value. 
This is the request body,

```
   {
    "Arguments":{
    "jobParameter":"{
  'key1':'keyname=subvalue',
  'key2':'value2'
}"

},
    "JobName":"jobname"
    }
```

**python dictionary = {
      'key1':'keyname=subvalue',
      'key2':'value2'
    }**

When I test the API by giving this as input, it gives an error,

> {
>     "__type": "SerializationException"
>   }

Please can anyone help with this?

Comment: This link suggests using escape characters for the quotes inside jobParameter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211335/serializationexceptionstart-of-structure-or-map-found-where-not-expected-api-gs

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that also gives the same error. And my header Content-Type  is  'application/x-amz-json-1.1'. is the issue with this?

Comment: I check this by adding Content-Type as 'application/json'. It also gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not recognizing as a valid JSON.
Try send something diferente as parameter of jobParameter to test.

Comment: I tried with the string value (not python dictionary). it  invokes glue job.But since it is wrong input, glue job is failing with an error.  To invoke glue job, I should pass python dictionary as jobParameter.

Comment: Alright, try to escape now with two single quotes ''. like this:  "jobParameter":"{ ''key1'':''keyname=subvalue'', ''key2':'value2''}"

Answer (score -1):

This problem often occur when a json item has as value another dict. Another solution is to pass it as a `json.dumps()`

```
import json
body = {
    "Arguments":{
    "jobParameter":{
        'key1':'keyname=subvalue',
        'key2':'value2'
        }    
    },
    "JobName":"jobname"
    }
body_parsed = json.dumps(body)
```

then in your request, you should do:

`requests.post(url=url, body=body_parsed , headers=headers)`